# How to get a list of logins and user mappings in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Server with several databases in it.

We use SQL-based authentication by creating logins and then mapping them to individual database users.

I am looking for a SQL query to get the list of all the logins, their user mapping in the databases, and their DB roles in each database.

Example of the expected output

| Login | Database | DB User | DB Roles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user01 | db01 | user01 | db_owner |
| user02 | db01 | user02 | db_reader, db_writer |

Answer (score 0):

I created stored procedure as below to get the list of all the logins, their user mapping in the databases, and their DB roles in each database.
Stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_dbUsersMap (@dbRole SYSNAME = '%')
AS
SELECT 
    Login = l.[name],
    DB_NAME() as DB_Name,
    db_User = bp.[name],
    db_Role = r.[name]
FROM 
    sys.database_role_members mmbr, -- The Role OR members associations table
    sys.database_principals r,     -- The DB Roles names table
    sys.database_principals bp,    -- The Role members table (database users)
    sys.server_principals l          -- The Login accounts table
WHERE   
     r.[principal_id] = mmbr.[role_principal_id]
    AND bp.[principal_id] = mmbr.[member_principal_id]
    AND l.[sid] = bp.[sid]
    AND r.[name] LIKE '%' + @dbRole + '%'
GO
```

It executed successfully.
Output:

[image]

I retrieve all databases information as mentioned below:

```
CREATE TABLE #usermap1 
  ( Login1 nvarchar(100),
    DB nvarchar(100),
    DBUser nvarchar(100),
    DBRole nvarchar(100)
  )

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? insert into #usermap1 exec sp_dbUsersMap' 

SELECT * FROM #usermap1
```

I gave output as I required.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Did you try this with Azure SQL Database?

Comment: It is working in Azure SQL Database, but sp_MSforeachdb not available Azure SQL Database, we may need to create one. here is the link for create sp_MSforeachdb stored procedure https://gist.github.com/metaskills/893599